# Ударение в слове ретропульсия

Tags: орфоэпия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где корректно ставить ударение в слове "ретропульсия"? Поиск в интернете не помог, увы.

Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобную терминологию лучше искать в гуглокнигах по словарям или энциклопедиям. Я нашёл пару словарей — в них ударение ставится на **у**.

[Ссылка 1](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=olvPAAAAMAAJ&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&dq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMw8SqlNnxAhXUhf0HHYk9CeAQ6AF6BAgDEAI), [ссылка 2](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=VJTHBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT845&dq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMw8SqlNnxAhXUhf0HHYk9CeAQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я не искал там, а только в интернет-словарях и справочниках (там без ударений). Буду иметь в виду.